# Can someone explain the different parameters in matplotlib.patches.arc?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I just want to understand the basic parameters and what they do specifically - width, height, angle, theta1, theta 2. I followed the official documentation and I understood what the centre is, but I don't get what the theta 1 or 2 does, or the angle does or what the length of the horizontal or vertical axis means. 
I tried experimenting with the parameters using different numbers but failed to hit upon an accurate result. 
I'm trying to create the arc of the 3-point area in the basketball court

Comment: The 3 point line has a radius of 6.75 meters, hence you need a half-circle with width=height=2*6.75. The circle starts at -90 and goes to 90 degrees, or vice versa depending on the side of the court. For circles you can ignore the `angle`. `matplotlib.patches.Arc((0,0), 2*6.75, 2*6.75, theta1=-90, theta2=90)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped me a ton!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Arc` type is a subclass of `Ellipse`, extended to add two values `theta1` and `theta2`. The behaviour of `angle` is the same for both `Ellipse` and `Arc` and determines the angle at which the ellipse is drawn.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.axis('off')

a = Ellipse((10, 45), 10, 3, 0, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

a = Ellipse((10, 40), 10, 3, 10, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

a = Ellipse((10, 35), 10, 3, 20, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

a = Ellipse((10, 30), 10, 3, 30, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

for a in range(0, 360, 40):
    a = Ellipse((10, 20), 10, 3, a, color='red', lw=1, fc='none')
    ax.add_patch(a)
```

This produces —

[image: elliipse rotation]

Note that for a perfect circle (an ellipse of equal `height` and `width`) this makes no difference (as a circle is rotationally symmetrical).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.axis('off')

a = Ellipse((10, 25), 10, 10, 0, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

a = Ellipse((10, 10), 10, 10, 45, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)
```

Both circles are the same.

[image: rotation of a circle]

The [Arc documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html#matplotlib.patches.Arc) for the `matplotlib.patches.Arc` explains that theta 1 & 2 are —

> `theta1`, `theta2` : `float`, optional
>
> Starting and ending angles of the arc in degrees. These values are relative to angle, .e.g. if angle = 45 and theta1 = 90 the absolute starting angle is 135. Default theta1 = 0, theta2 = 360, i.e. a complete ellipse.

The key statement there is "Default theta1 = 0, theta2 = 360, i.e. a complete ellipse." — these parameters are used to draw partial ellipses, to create an arc. `theta1` is the angle (or position on) the ellipse at which to start *drawing*, and `theta2` is when to stop. Note that the calculation of the ellipse is unaffected.

The following code draws a series of arcs which should make the logic apparent —

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.axis('off')

# A complete ellipse, using theta1=0, theta2=360.
a = Arc((10, 45), 10, 3, 0, 0, 360, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

# Reduce theta2 to 350, last 10 deg of ellipse not drawn.
a = Arc((10, 40), 10, 3, 0, 0, 350, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

# Rotate the ellipse (angle=90), theta1 & theta2 are relative to start angle & rotate too.
a = Arc((10, 30), 10, 3, 90, 0, 350, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

# Rotate the ellipse (angle=180), as above.
a = Arc((10, 20), 10, 3, 180, 0, 350, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

# Draw the top half of the ellipse (theta 0-180 deg). 
a = Arc((10, 10), 10, 3, 0, 0, 180, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)

# Draw the bottom half of the ellipse (theta 180-360 deg).
a = Arc((10, 5), 10, 3, 0, 180, 360, color='red', lw=1)
ax.add_patch(a)
```

This produces the following image, with arcs drawn above going from top to bottom. Compare with the comments in the code for explanation.

[image: theta 1 and theta2 Arc examples]

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me out.

Comment: Excellent answer, @mfitzp. I esp. appreciate the way in which you sequentially modify each example to illustrate the role of each parameter